# PCIe bandwidth utilization surge when switching from 2k to 4k framebuffer in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, profiling, gpu, framebuffer

I render a simple scene with 50 drawcalls for main scene, shadow, reflection and postprocess maps overall. For the following test I set shadow map size to 4k (4096x4096) and will vary reflection map size.

The test will run on NVidia GTX 650 with 1Gb of video memory. When the test application is running, only 600+ mb of video memory is used by all running applications, so I have 200-300 mb free video RAM. Vsync is disabled and there are no FPS boundaries in the application, so GPU utilization is 99%-100%. All metrics are measured with Nvidia driver tool:

[image]

OK, let's start the application and measure it's FPS depending on reflection map size:

- 1k and below - 110 FPS
- 2k - 102 FPS
- 4k - 38 FPS

Switching from 2k to 4k reflection texture significantly drops FPS rate, while the measuring utility shows abnormal PCI bandwidth utilization, which increases from 1% to 65%. At the same time, amount of used video memory does not exceed 700Mb (of 1Gb available).

Ok, let's run [Nvidia graphics debugger](https://developer.nvidia.com/linux-graphics-debugger) and see what is the heaviest OpenGL call. It shows that `glClear` for reflection map takes more than 10 ms! Switching reflection map to 2k drops this value to thousands of nanoseconds, which is OK for present day hardware. You may say that `glClear` actually flushes all previous rendering commands, but if I disable clear calls in the debugger, the framerate increases up to 90-100 FPS.

This behavior also may be reproduced with Emscripten + Chrome, but in chrome the slow functions are `glDrawElements`, which draw terrain to shadowmap. What is even stranger, draw calls for main scene terrain (with much heavier fragment shader) take less time.

So what is the problem? Why does the driver transfer something through PCIe while having 300Mb of free video memory? May the reasonbe in improper texture or framebuffer usage?